# How to keep browser extensions installed in debugging browser Window?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, browser, config

I'd like to customize my browser which runs when I starts debugging in VS Code. Browser always starts clean with no extensions, I'd like to have installed extensions like Redux Devtools, React Devtools. Anyone knows how to cofnigure that?

Answer (score 0):

To run Chrome browser with default user config (including extensions) this should be added to the launch.json debugger ocnfiguration:

```
"runtimeArgs": [
    "--profile-directory=Default"
]
```